# LiquiBase ValidationFailedException. Checksum changed without reason

Tags: liquibase

I've got some changelog files and when i try to generate sql files for them i get:
**ValidationFailedException**.

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     13 change sets check sum
          db-changelogs/test1.xml::test-1::rw is now: 7:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

The problem is **i haven't made any changes** in these files. My collegues work on the same git branch and it works perfectly for them.

I've checked textCoding and some other things but it still doesnt work.
I run it with ant script.

My database-changelog **(new-db-changelog.xml)**:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <include file="db-changelogs/testl.xml"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Change log **(test1.xml)**:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

        <changeSet id="test-1" author="rem" >
            <ext:sqlWrapper context="common-schema">
                <![CDATA[
    CREATE TABLE common.test(
      id bigint NOT NULL,
      "name" character varying,
      CONSTRAINT test_lb_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
                ]]>
            </ext:sqlWrapper>
        </changeSet>

    </databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: You need to explain what code you have got, what is your setup etc.

Comment: I've added some details. The problem is i dont know why only I get this check-sum mismatch even if its just cloned git project

Comment: What version of liquibase are you running? Could this be the following bug? https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1950

Comment: Its 3.1.1. I know that bug, but in my company we all run on the same version and only I have that problem.

Comment: If you run liquibase with logLevel=DEBUG it will output what it is md5sum-ing to get the checksum. If you post that output it may help debug the problem. Is there an OS-difference or charset difference between the machines?

Comment: MD5 was really diffrent between files on my local machine and my friend, even though they were the same. As for file encoding all files were encoded using UTF-8. 

I gave up on this problem and reinstall my linux,and it is now working.

Comment: Did you have a previous installation of your project in place?

Answer (score 3):

Add attribute `runOnChange="true"`

```
<changeSet id="test-1" author="rem" runOnChange="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

We just discovered that 3.1.1 seems to make a difference in whitespaces when calculating checksums. We have some changes with pure SQL that I happened to reformat from spaces to tabs and the checksums got changed.

Could this be the case perhaps?